# XDocument return all element names and values to two separate lists

Tags: c#, xml, list, linq-to-xml

I have an XML document that looks like the following:

```
<Settings>
  <!-- Comment1 -->
  <A> 1 </A>
  <!-- Comment2 -->
  <B> 2 </B>
  <!-- Comment3 -->
  <C> 3 </C>
  <!-- Comment4 -->
  <D> 4 </D>
</Settings>
```

How can I add the element names (A,B,C,D) to a list and also the element values (1,2,3,4) to another list. Note that in reality the XML file I am dealing with has over 1000+ lines of code so I need a more efficient way than just pulling each value and element one by one and adding it to a list...

Comment: Did you tried something?

Comment: You want 2 list one for the elment name the other for the value? Why not a dictionary?

Comment: Does this help: `document.Root.Elements().Select(x => ...`?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/how-to-work-with-dictionaries-using-linq-to-xml#example-1, is this exemple covering your case?

Comment: But instead of going from root you go from Setting Descendants. Do you have element outside of setting or setting is your root?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To parse part of the Xml into a Dictionary using [LinqToXML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/linq-to-xml-overview) Load your Xdocument.
Select everything under the Settings. 
Enumerate those Elements and make them a Dictionary.

If there are duplicates Elements, replace `ToDictionary` by `Select`.

```
string input = @"<root>
<Settings>
    <A> 1 </A>
    <B> 2 </B>
    <C> 3 </C>
    <D> 4 </D>
</Settings>
<Hello>World</Hello>
<Foo>Bar</Foo>
</root>";

XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse(input);

var result = xdoc.Descendants("Settings")
    .Elements()
    .ToDictionary(
        el => el.Name.LocalName,
        el => el.Value 
    );
```

Result:

```
Dumping object(System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[String,String])
  [
   [A,  1 ]
   ,
   [B,  2 ]
   ,
   [C,  3 ]
   ,
   [D,  4 ]
]
```

Acessing value like `settings["A"]`.

[LiveDemo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/7q51IM)

---

NB: here the dictionary is "`[String,String]`", but you can convert the value to fit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code.

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Declare and load your xml file
            XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
            xmlDoc.Load("XMLFile.xml");

            //Instatiate the object where you want to store the list values
            XMLData xmlData = new XMLData();
            xmlData.listKeys = new List<string>();
            xmlData.listValues = new List<string>();

            //Pick the settings parent node 
            XmlNode xmlSettingsNode = xmlDoc.FirstChild;

            //Loop through the list and add name and values to list
            foreach (XmlNode xmlNode in xmlSettingsNode.ChildNodes)
            {
                //Ignore commented lines
                if (xmlNode.NodeType != XmlNodeType.Comment)
                {
                    xmlData.listKeys.Add(xmlNode.Name);
                    xmlData.listValues.Add(xmlNode.InnerText);
                }
            }
        }
    }

//Data model for storing list data
    public class XMLData
    {
       public List<string> listKeys { get; set; }
       public List<string> listValues { get; set; }

    }
```

Comment: List key and list value is a bad idea. nothing keep the order of element in a list there is no index.

Comment: Yeah, dictionaries could be used in place of list to store it like a key-value pair, but if you look at the question, list is what he is asking for.